# Determining T-SQL / DDL that cannot be executed in a transaction

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

There are various statements and system procedures that can't be executed within a transaction, with an error message of "not allowed..." (e.g., `create database`) or "cannot be executed..." (e.g., `exec sp_addrole`).

Is there a rule or set of rules that would indicate whether a given procedure/statement isn't allowed in a transaction? Is there a listing thereof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an official Microsoft resource, [but the most comprehensive list I've found so far](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Recommended_Best_Practices_for_Transactions)...

- `ALTER DATABASE`
- `BACKUP LOG`
- `BACKUP DATABASE`
- `RESTORE LOG`
- `RESTORE DATABASE`
- `RECONFIGURE`
- `UPDATE STATISTICS`
- `LOAD DATABASE`
- `LOAD TRANSACTION`
- `CREATE DATABASE`
- `DISK INIT`
- `DROP DATABASE`
- System stored procedures that alter the `MASTER` database

The final item is a pretty broad category... but you can reasonably predict what types of system stored procedures would be altering the `MASTER` database... essentially anything that functions at the server level instead of the database level.

Comment: From the top of my head, I also think that Full Text Indexes or Catalogs cannot be altered inside a transaction